# What should Trump do to get in?

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge

There was a Top Secret meeting of many world leaders in Geneva. The leaders must enter a secret code on a computer screen to get in the room where the meeting was.

First came Prime Minister T. May.

The computer screen displayed

**BKS**

The Prime Minister entered

**5601**

The door opened and she went in

Then came President Putin

The display read

**CBK**

Putin entered

**R522**

The door opened and he went in.

Then came Chancellor Angela Merkel

The computer displayed

**SBC**

The Chancellor entered

**254G**

The door opened and she went in.

Then came President Trump

The computer displayed

**KBS**

Trump entered

**5461**

The door did not open.

What should he have entered to get in?

Comment: (I deleted a politically-jokey comment. It wasn't terribly offensive or anything, but best to stay away from potentially incendiary things.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The challenge posed by the computer can be decoded from its individual letters as:

> **B** - last 2 digits of birth year
>  **C** - First letter of country
>  **K** - Number of kids
>  **S** - Number of spouses

In the case of Donald Trump, for a challenge of KBS, the response would be:

> K = **5** kids
>  B = 19**46**
>  S = **3** spouses
>
>  Giving a response of **5463**

Comment: Probably the intended answer, but one of those needs an "in English" qualifier.